# Wierd problem with Table and Evaluate

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, parametric-functions

I have a very unpleasent problem with Mathematica, precisely with Table and/or Evaluate. After solving a parametric system with ParametricNDSolve, I'd like to collect the values of the solutions $f_3(x)$ and $v_3(x)$ using Table. However this works only for one of the two functions. The code is the following

```
system = {
   f'[x] == g[x], 
   g'[x] == -2 g[x]/x + 2*f[x]*v[x]^2/(x^2 - 1/x),
   v'[x] == a[x], 
   a'[x] == -((2x + 1/x^2)/(x^2 - 1/x))*a[x] - 2*a[x]/x - (f[x]/(x^2 - 1/x))^2*v[x] + (-2/(x^2 -1/x))*v[x],
   (*initial conditions below*)
   f[1.01] == 0 , 
   f[1000000] == 1, 
   v[1.01] == k, 
   a[1.01] == (-2/3)*k};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {f, v}, {x, 1.01, 1000000}, {k}];

datapotential = 
  Table[{i, Evaluate[f[3][x] /. sol[[1]]] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}];

datascalar = 
  Table[{i, Evaluate[v[3][x] /. sol[[1]]] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}];
```

the first Table correctly gives me

```
{{{10, 0.552959}, {11, 0.583077}, {12, 0.6095}, {13, 0.632846}, {14, 
   0.653609}, {15, 0.672188}, {16, 0.688902}, {17, 0.704015}, {18, 
   0.717743}, {19, 0.730266}, {20, 0.741735}}}
```

while the second one gives

```
{{{10, v[3][10]}, {11, v[3][11]}, {12, v[3][12]}, {13, v[3][13]}, {14,
    v[3][14]}, {15, v[3][15]}, {16, v[3][16]}, {17, v[3][17]}, {18, 
   v[3][18]}, {19, v[3][19]}, {20, v[3][20]}}}
```

like it isn't able to evaluate $v_3(x)$ at the desired points! The wierd fact is that I can evaluate and plot both the functions $f$ and $v$ for every value of the parameter! For instance I can compute the value of $v_3$ in $x=4$ and get

```
Evaluate[v[3][4] /. sol]
(*0.997863620075214*).
```

I tried with many values of the parameter (not only 3) and many intervals but the problem is always there. I've also tried to literally copy and paste the line, and it works if I substitute $v$ with $f$!
I didn't find anyone with this problem, but any suggestion to similar problems is appreciated. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `v` on the correct part of the solution as follows

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {f, v}, {x, 1.01, 1000000}, {k}];

datapotential = 
 Table[{i, Evaluate[f[3][x] /. sol[[1]]] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]

datascalar = 
 Table[{i, Evaluate[v[3][x] /. sol[[2]]] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]
```

Now both Tables will generate the data

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You just had the wrong part number in the second case and that is why it was  not evaluating.

A better way is to just use `/.sol` for both and not having to worry about the part number. Like this

```
datapotential = 
 Table[{i, Evaluate[f[3][x] /. sol] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]
datascalar = 
 Table[{i, Evaluate[v[3][x] /. sol] /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note**: Thanks to comment below. You actually do not `Evaluate` in this case. So you just do

```
datapotential = Table[{i, f[3][x] /. sol /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]

datascalar = Table[{i, v[3][x] /. sol /. x -> i}, {i, 10, 20}]
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `Evaluate` isn't doing anything here, it could just be removed

Comment: @LukasLang You are right. It is not needed here. I guess help on `NDSolve` uses `Evaluate` all over the place, and so it becomes just a habit to add it whenever one uses `NDSolve`. I'll remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful and solved my problem.